# Iran "sanctions"?

Tags: international, commerce

In the news I keep hearing about "sanctions" on Iran. For example, [one article published today](http://www.reuters.com/article/us-iran-oil-exports-idUSKCN0YR0XU), said that "sanctions were lifted", but that "some sanctions still remain". Such news stories are invariably vague about exactly what these "sanctions" are. US law? EU law? UN resolution? What?

How can I find out exactly what these "sanctions" are and their terms?

Answer (score 1):

From the US perspective, a readable summary of what the internet believes can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/U.S._sanctions_against_Iran). For access to more authoritative documents, a good starter would be the [State Department page](http://www.state.gov/e/eb/tfs/spi/iran/index.htm). A summary of relevant statutes are [found here](http://www.state.gov/e/eb/tfs/spi/iran/statutes/index.htm), and executive orders [are here](http://www.state.gov/e/eb/tfs/spi/iran/eo/index.htm). Treasury also has [a page](https://www.treasury.gov/resource-center/sanctions/Programs/Pages/iran.aspx) with lots of information on Iran sanctions. I'm not sure there is any way to get an exhaustive and definitive list, but this is a start.